# Как сделать выборку из двух таблиц одним запросом?

Tags: php, sql, sqlite3

Есть sqlite база с двумя таблицами

```
t1
|id| name |lang|city|date  |
|--|------|----|----|------|
 1 |vasya |ru  |msk |1.1.70|
 2 |petya |ru  |spb |1.1.70|
|--|------|----|----|------|

t2
|id| name |    email    |tel |
|--|------|-------------|----|
 1 |vasya |ru@localhost |1111|
 2 |petya |ru@localhost1|2222|
 3 |vasya |             |3333|
 4 |petya |             |4444|
|--|------|-------------|----|
```

php скриптом хочу получить результат

```
1 vasya ru msk 1.1.70 ru@localhost  1111
                                    3333
2 petya ru spb 1.1.70 ru@localhost1 2222
                                    4444
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну первое - в идеале надо б изменить таблицу 2:

```
t1
|id| name |lang|city|date  |
|--|------|----|----|------|
 1 |vasya |ru  |msk |1.1.70|
 2 |petya |ru  |spb |1.1.70|
|--|------|----|----|------|

t2
|id| name_ID |    email    |tel |
|--|---------|-------------|----|
 1 |1        |ru@localhost |1111|
 2 |2        |ru@localhost1|2222|
 3 |1        |             |3333|
 4 |2        |             |4444|
|--|---------|-------------|----|
```

ну а далее (SQL):

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.lang, t1.city, t1.date, t2.email, t2.tel from t1 
JOIN t2 ON (id= name_ID)
```

ну или в вашем примере `(name=name)`

Comment: SELECT t1.name, t1.lang, t1.city, t1.date, t2.email, t2.tel from t1 JOIN t2 ON (name=name);
Error: ambiguous column name: name

Comment: https://www.sql.ru/forum/749690/pomogite-ambiguous-column-name  - собственно из кода ошибки видно - одинаковое имя колонок не нравится. Либо алиас присвоить ,либо переименовать, либо как я выше писала - айдишниками во второй  таблице сделать. В общем любой вариант, чтобы названия колонок для метчинга не были с одинаковым названием

Comment: Переименовал name на name_test в таблице t2.
    SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.lang, t1.city, t1.date, t2.email, t2.tel from t1 JOIN t2 
    ON (name=name_test);
получаю
    1|vasya|ru|msk|1.1.70||3333
    1|vasya|ru|msk|1.1.70|ru@localhost|1111
    2|petya|ru|spb|1.1.70||4444
    2|petya|ru|spb|1.1.70|ru@localhost1|2222
Нужно
    1|vasya|ru|msk|1.1.70|ru@localhost|1111
    ||||||3333
    2|petya|ru|spb|1.1.70|ru@localhost1|2222
    ||||||4444